# python regex skipping optional words not working

Tags: python, regex

I have been trying to find matches where they may be optional words in the string that need to be ignored if they are present.

The code I tried is:

```
    import re
    str = '''
         topping consensus estimates 
         topping analysis' consensus estimate
         topping estimate
    '''
    for m in re.finditer(r'(?P<p3c>topping\s+(?:\w+\s(?!estimate)){0,2}(estimate))',str):
        print(m.group())
    print('done')
```

I want to get all three cases found in the string but only get the last.  I want to skip up to two words between topping and estimate but cannot guarantee that they will be analysis and consensus. I tried with `(?:\w+\s(?!estimate)){0,2}` to skip up to two word to get the results but it is not working for some reason.

Comment: What is "not working"? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to get "topping estimate" as the result. What you *really* want is to check whether each line starts with `topping` followed by 2 or fewer words, then `estimate` or `estimates`.

This regex will help you:

```
^topping(\s\S+){0,2}\sestimates?\s*$
```

Match this against each line, or multiple lines if you turn on `m`. It will tell you whether the string satisfies the requirement.

Comment: Thanks,  I needed to modify your suggestion to fit my needs but you have the right approach.   I am using just r'topping(\s\S+){0,2}\sestimate' since I do not know where they will be in the text.

Comment: @Pat If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Comment: @Pat Define "no longer works". What are you trying to match? What do you expect it to match? What actually matched?

Comment: @Pat Try using `search` instead of `findall`

Comment: I don't know what happened,  but I restarted from scratch and compile is now working!!!   Not sure what the problem was but it seems to be gone. Thanks again Sweeper for your help.